# Adding some tags between one specific tag opening and closing in linux

Tags: xml, linux, sed

Hi i have my config file where i have to add some tags between two tags as show below

```
<blacklist>


</blacklist>
```

I need to add some other tags in between these two tags as below

```
 <blacklist>
<blacklistEntry>
<groupNames>A,B,C<\/groupNames>
<errorCode>0222<\/errorCode>
</blacklistEntry>
</blacklist>
```

I tried using sed but not able to achieve this. Please help on this

Comment: Do not parse XML with `sed`. Use an XML parser instead. Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: i am supposed do that with sed for testing an scenario in automation after changing the config file.

Comment: I have tried the below  sed -i 's/<blacklist>/<blacklistEntry><groupNames>abc<\/groupNames> <errorCode>0222<\/errorCode>/<\/blacklistEntry>/d' path/config/webapp.xml     but it is giving me error

Comment: [edit] your original question with this info. We cannot understand code in comments.

Comment: hi fedorqui thanks for the reply .. i have modified it as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed -i 's/<blacklist>/<blacklist>\n<blacklistEntry>\n<groupNames>A\,B\,C<\/groupNames>\n<errorCode>0222<\/errorCode>\n<\/blacklistEntry>/g' file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed program that does what you want.  Copy it into a file, say `myprog.sed`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sed -f

/<blacklist>/a \
<blacklistEntry>\
<groupNames>A,B,C<\/groupNames>\
<errorCode>0222<\/errorCode>\
</blacklistEntry>
```

Then run it:

```
chmod +x myprog.sed
./myprog.sed myinput.xml
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for the reply can i have it as a single line command instead of a script file.